# Select Custom data with Cayenne return empty lines

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, empty-list, apache-cayenne

I'm trying to select data from 2 diff mysql tables:

```
SELECT 

    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, startdatetime, enddatetime)), 
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, startdatetime, enddatetime) * hourly),

    SUM(CASE 
    WHEN TIME(startdatetime) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '12:00:00' THEN 'test', 

    SUM(CASE 
    WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, startdatetime, enddatetime) <= 9 THEN 'TEST'
    ELSE 'TEST2'
    END) 

    FROM date, tarif
    GROUP BY userid, MONTH(startdatetime), YEAR(startdatetime)
```

In my code, I have :

```
SQLTemplate select = new SQLTemplate(DateInfo.class, query);
return CayenneUtil.getContext().performQuery(select);
```

I tried too :

```
CayenneUtil.getContext().performGenericQuery(select).firstList()
```

But I received 4 empty lines instead of 4 lines with data.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `select.setFetchingDataRows(true)` as by default `SQLTemplate` will try to convert result into data objects (`DateInfo` in your case).
After this flag set query will return `List<DataRow>` and `DataRow` is a Cayenne internal extension of plain `java.util.HashMap`.